# The title of the article does not appear in full in url wordpress

Tags: wordpress

When you use WordPress, the full article title does not appear in url .
now use (Custom Permalinks) plugin .
Is there a solution without using plugin .

Comment: Isn't this just a setting? Go to`settings -> Permalinks` and set them to `postname`

Comment: @Interactive I did it but the same problem . Article title is incomplete in url

Comment: Can you provide a url to a post?

Comment: Can you also do the following: - disable all plugins and added themes. This way you know for sure it's not the wp installation. After that activate one by one so you can see what causes this to happen.

Comment: (Custom Permalinks) plugin works well. But I want it to be automatic without using plugin

Comment: Yes you stated that in your question. But did you try what I suggested? You can also review the plugin and see how they do it.